# How to get String[] outside OnCreate()

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop, oncreate

Here I'm using the following code to create a `string current[]` using for loop:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_imageactivity);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String jsonArray = intent.getStringExtra("jsonArray");
   try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonArray);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
            String current_name[] = { obj.getString("current_name") }; // array
       }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}    

// Log.e(TAG,"VALUES" + Arrays.toString(current_name));
```

Now I want to call this `current_name[]` outside `OnCreate` or some other method. By using this code I can't `Log` outside `OnCreate`. So please help me to solve this issue. Answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Declare this array as activity variable

Comment: create global variable in your class for current_name[] so you can access it in another Member functions in Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the array as a member of the activity and in the onCreate initialize it only

```
try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
        current_name[i] =  obj.getString("current_name"); 
   }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: In the `current_name` it has only one value(i.e last value).

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array` now this is the error it shows.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
String current_name[] = {};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_imageactivity);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String jsonArray = intent.getStringExtra("jsonArray");
try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
        current_name[i] =obj.getString("current_name"); // array
   }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Now you can access String out of oncreate.